# Empty validation message in Spring project after 'gradle eclipse'

Tags: eclipse, spring, war, gradle

After I migrated from building Spring project with Maven to building it with gradle I have weird empty validation errors.

I noticed that path `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` is under `Web App Libraries` build path group, though with Maven-import configuration it was just in src directory.

Using `gradle cleanEclipse`, refreshing and clearing project, nor removing all `.metadata`, `.settings`, `bin`, `.classpath`, `.project` directories didn't helped.

Aside from that WAR file is built fine.

Configuration:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                        SERVER'S TASKS' CONFIGURATION
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

configure(serverProjects) {
    apply plugin : 'war'
    apply plugin : 'eclipse-wtp'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

project(':Server') {
    war {
        destinationDir serverDir
    }
}

...

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                      SERVER'S PROJECTS' CONFIGURATION
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

project(':Server') {
    eclipse {    
        project {
            natures "com.springsource.sts.gradle.core.nature"
        }

        classpath {
            containers "com.springsource.sts.gradle.classpathcontainer"
        }
    }
}

...

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                    SERVER'S DEPENDENCIES' CONFIGURATION
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

configure(serverProjects) {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public' }
    }
}

project(':Server') {
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

What can I do to ensure that project would be imported into Eclipse without this problem?

EDIT:

The only information visible to me is this one: [image: empty validation error]

As far as I noticed project build by maven didn't have any errors and only a little amount of warnings. Right now I see that simple `<form:errors path="field"/>` cries about "List being generic".

EDIT2:

I managed to get rid of some of the issues by changing project configuration to:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                      SERVER'S PROJECTS' CONFIGURATION
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

project(':Server') {
    eclipse {    
        project {
            natures      "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature"
            buildCommand "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder"
        }
    }
}
```

but the main problem - validation error with no information about what it is concerned - still remains.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the problem is? Is there any useful information in the Eclipse error log?

Comment: I added some some details to the problem's description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During warning cleanup I decided to remove file `src/test/resources/log4j.xml` since it was douplicate of a `src/main/resources/log4j.xml`. In that very moment empty validation error disappeared.

If anyone else get similar error, he should try to get rid of all warnings, since apparently they are able to make project fail Eclipse validation.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue (I think). I solved it by right-clicking the project and selecting "Validate". This re-executed the validations and cleared the error.

Comment: For me, doing this removed the error in one project, but not in the other. For this other project it says "The validation was completed, one error was discovered"  but _still_ doesn't say what the error is. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, encoding makes this issue.
My source is encoded by UTF-8, but eclipse was set to MS949.
If eclipse or workspace encoding setting is changed to UTF-8, the empty validation error may be removed.

Sometimes, the issue is not removed though right encoding is set. At this time, I change encoding to any other type and then rollback it to UTF-8. Then, it may be removed.